# Is there a way to delay evaluation of the string accompanying error output with NUnit?

Tags: c++-cli, nunit

I'm using NUnit to verify some code and have a problem reporting helpful information. My tests go something along the following lines:

```
Assert::IsTrue(myClassInstance.SomeMethodToTest(), "Test failed: {0}", myClassInstance.LastError);
```

The problem is that the `LastError` property is evaluated before the method is tested so the last error is blank.

Is there any way to delay the evaluation of the last error to give the function some more meaningful output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's a big bummer, but you are invoking Undefined Behavior here.  NUnit was originally designed for Java, ported pretty well to C# and VB.NET.  Languages that promise strict left-to-right function argument evaluation order in their language spec.  So that `Assert.IsTrue()` method has well defined behavior in those languages.

But not in C++/CLI, it takes advantage of the UB rule in C++.  No doubt inspired by the [ParamArray] for the 3rd argument, it first polishes off that one before evaluating the other arguments.  You get right-to-left order.  Shooting off the hip, I'd say that this has something to do with varargs emulation.

Not so sure what to recommend, sailing around UB is forever tricky.  You can technically provide your own overloads of `Assert::IsTrue()` with one or more Object^ arguments.  The compiler will pick those instead of the [ParamArray] overload.  Or avoid the [ParamArray] overload completely and use `String::Format()` to generate the *message* argument instead.  You'll now get left-to-right.  That's *still* UB however, it looks okay but I can't promise this will work with every possible set of argument expressions.

Ouch, sorry.

Comment: `String::Format` sounds like it's worth a shot at least. I had done that in several places previously which would explain why I was surprised I'd not encountered this before..